# Looking at the Wigner function plot of a given state, how do we know if it's a good option for use as a qubit?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-states, wigner-transform, non-gaussianity

I am looking at GKP and cat states. Wigner plots are newish to me, and I'm trying to get an intuitive feel for the imformation they impart.

Just by looking at a Wigner plot, can one discern whether the state shown would make a good qubit? What does one look for? Are certain, say, symmetries, important?

E.g., I know the grid-like pattern of a GKP state means some error-correction is inherent.

(Asking here too as well as on the quantum computing stack)